# Unable to find the libnl RPM package to satisfy CrowdStrike Falcon Sensor dependency on RHEL 8

Tags: linux, package, redhat, rpm, yum

I have to install falcon-sensor rpm package for Crowdstrike to be present on server and it needed libnl RPM package as dependencies.

I can get it from  https://rpmfind.net/ as below and able to install on RHEL8.

```
#dnf install https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/Packages/libnl-1.1.4-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

but i do not want to download it from rpm finder website.

I would like to do it using redhat repository similarly we do for other rpm packages ex. telnet,

```
#yum install libnl
```

Whenever i am hitting above command getting below error.

```
No match for argument: libnl
Error: Unable to find a match: libnl
```

I have tried enabling below repositories of RHEL 8.

```
codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms        Red Hat CodeReady L enabled: 1,842
codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-source-rpms Red Hat CodeReady L enabled:   489
*epel                                         Extra Packages for  enabled: 4,401
rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms                    Red Hat Enterprise  enabled: 8,420
rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms                       Red Hat Enterprise  enabled: 3,378
rhel-8-baseos-rhui-source-rpms                Red Hat Enterprise  enabled:   779
rhui-client-config-server-8                   Red Hat Update Infr enabled:     5
```

How can i get libnl rpm by enabling repositories in RHEL 8?

Comment: Recent releases of falcon-sensor for el8 do not have the libnl dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `libnl` was [explicitly removed in RHEL8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index), so you need to find the RHEL8 version of the RPM you are trying to install.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Anyways i found the package name its libnl3 for RHEL8.

Comment: Hello @SantoshGarole, I have the same problem. I installed libnl3, but it is still the same. Can you please share with me the fix that you did?

Comment: @AliOurag - It was resolved for me by installing libnl3

Answer (score -1):

You can go the [link](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libnl3-3.2.28-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) and this will take you the rpm and then you can download it ad install it manually using rpm command.
But the package was never added to RedHat global repository for RHEL8 so you might not find it in the repository.

Comment: Using packages on RHEL 8 that have been built for RHEL 7 is not a good idea.